# How can I require at least one checkbox be checked before another form show (Visual Basic 2010)

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, visual-studio-2010

In my Form1 i have 5 check box, 1 list box, and 2 buttons. 1 button (select all)  is for checking all the 5 checkbox and 1 (proceed button) is for proceeding to the next form which is Form2. My main goal in this Form is when user fill all the requirements and press the proceed button he/she will proceed to the next form (Form2) but when one is missing a message box will appear stating that one of the field is missing. User can click any of those checkbox and by selecting select all button all the checkbox will be checked but when he proceed to press the proceed button without checking any of those checkbox same messagebox will appear notifying that no checkbox are checked.

I try this code but it needed all the 5 checkbox checked before it proceeds to next form.

firelevel is the listbox
station1btn to station5btn is the checkbox

```
If firelevel.Text = String.Empty 
    Or station1btn.Checked = False 
    Or station2btn.Checked = False 
    Or station3btn.Checked = False 
    Or station4btn.Checked = False 
    Or station5btn.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("MISSING: Please fill all the field to complete your report", 
            MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "REPORT UNSUCESSFUL")


Else
    Me.Hide()
    CONFIRMFORM.Show()
    My.Settings.Save()
```

I already tried to change the `Or` to `And`, but it keeps advancing even the listbox is empty or all 5 is unchecked.

Comment: You should be using [`AND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator) instead of [`Or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator) if you are trying to ensure that none of them have a value. Read the links for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using but you could simply change the logic in your if statement to AND so

```
If cb1 is notchecked (AND/&&) cb2 is notchecked (AND/&&) cb3 is notchecked (AND/&&) cb4 is notchecked (AND/&&) cb5 is notchecked
```

This will prevent the form from advancing if none of the chackboxes are not checked! If one is then the if will fail!

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that at least one checkbox is checked, we need to use the `And` operator. The way you have it written, it's returning `True` if *any* checkbox is unchecked, whereas we want it to return `True` if *all* checkboxes are unchecked.

We can enclose the checkbox validations in parenthesis to force those comparisons to return a single `True` or `False` for the checkboxes, and we can `Or` that result with the textbox `Text` validation:

```
If firelevel.Text = String.Empty 
    Or (station1btn.Checked = False 
    And station2btn.Checked = False 
    And station3btn.Checked = False 
    And station4btn.Checked = False 
    And station5btn.Checked = False)
Then
    MsgBox("MISSING: Please fill all the field to complete your report", 
            MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "REPORT UNSUCESSFUL")
Else
    Me.Hide()
    CONFIRMFORM.Show()
    My.Settings.Save()
```

You can read more about the [`And`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator) and [`Or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator) operators at these links.

Answer (score 0):

you can try asigning values to each checkbox and only acced to form2 if the value is 5, i mean...

```
public class Program
{
    public int CheckBox_Status = 0; 
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
    ///
    ///Do this to all your CheckBOX'S increment by one for example
    ///
    public void CheckBox1_OnClick()
    {
        CheckBox_Status += 1;
    }
    ///
    ///The in your code when you evaluate all your conditions filled correctly
    ///you give access
    public void Open_Form2()
    {
        if(CheckBox_Status==5)
        {
            Form2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            messagebox.show("Check your data something is missing!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment sir but im using visual basic 2010. each of the checkbox has string value that when checked the label in the next form will be replace by the string value of the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You should use groupbox containing the checkboxes, which will make the iteration on the checkboxes easy. Once done, you can figure out the checked items by iterating through them. See the answers [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ae94f0d6-0380-4715-a617-5e4e38bd93a8/group-box-with-checkboxes?forum=vbgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using an Array to hold the CheckBoxes. This allows us to use a LINQ query to determine if all of them are unchecked:

```
Dim cbs() As CheckBox = {station1btn, station2btn, station3btn, station4btn, station5btn}
Dim noneSelected As Boolean = cbs.All(Function(x) Not x.Checked)
If firelevel.Text.Trim = String.Empty OrElse noneSelected Then
    MsgBox("MISSING: Please fill all the field to complete your report",
    MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "REPORT UNSUCESSFUL")
Else
    ' ... do something in here ...
End If
```